# Appending to bytearray fails

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, byte

I am attempting to build a byte array but I keep getting a type error when appending:

to_send = bytearray(first_byte)
to_send.append(bytes(4))

The debug message is saying int cannot be appended to byte array, I then tested

x = bytes(4)

and x is a byte object, it's very strange since x is literally an empty byte array.

Comment: If I understand you, you should use extend instead of append, for adding multiple bytes

Comment: Thanks, got it! For some reason I thought append allowed lists to be appended.